# Creating related table from existing parent table with automatic update

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008, I need to create a child table from parent big table copying it's values in two columns and updates automatically. These values must be distinct and copy into corresponding two columns in new table. The whole idea would be making reference table with these distinct values and make relation with parent table. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want a view, but beyond that, your question is too vague to make any real suggestions

Comment: Please, add sample data and expected output

Comment: Let's say big has 10 columns where new table copies two of them with distinct values into its two columns respectively and updates any changes on these original two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Enkhzul,

You'll want to create a VIEW. A VIEW will simply run a SELECT query in the background against any tables you request in the query and display as instructed. Syntax will be:

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO
CREATE VIEW [VIEWNAME] AS
(
    select statement here
)
```

After that you just need to do a SELECT query against the newly created VIEW.